# How to download pictures from a website using terminal

Tags: terminal, macos

What terminal command should I use to download all Leonardo DiCaprio pictures of this website to my Desktop : http://leonardodicapriofan.com/photos/thumbnails.php?album=334

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell if this is serious or if I am being rickrolled, but the command below will attempt to download all images in numeric range `0000` to `9999`. Find the lowest and highest numbers of images linked and insert those. However a lot of sites have protections against direct downloading, and this might be one of them...

```
curl -O -s "http://leonardodicapriofan.com/photos/albums/movies/django-unchained/screen-caps/normal_[0000-9999].jpg"
```

Comment: Your not being rickrolled. IS actually a really important question for me, I bought a Teensy board and I am trying to develop my first program for it, and I want to make it download all leo pictures and scramble on the computer

Comment: Anyway I can do this without being banned?

Comment: I don't think so. Most larger sites have prevention against that kind of thing. There are some other command-line browsers and python libraries that will allow you to browse more like a real person and not a machine.